# Dyet in XeTeX using Futura Font

Tags: fonts, fontspec

I need to use the Futura font, but am struggling to get the dyet (crossed D symbol) to render. When I add the fontenc package, it changes all of my fonts out of the Futura font that I have already set. Any help would be great!

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc} 
\usepackage[paperheight=7.5in,paperwidth=7.5in,left=1in,right=1in,top=1in,bottom=1in]{geometry}
\usepackage{graphicx, amsmath, xcolor, wrapfig, float, subfiles, enumitem, xcoffins, atbegshi, fontspec}
\usepackage[none]{hyphenat}
\usepackage[font=small,labelfont=bf]{caption}
\setmainfont{Futura}

%\ProvideTextCommand{\DJ}{OT1}{\raisebox{0.25ex}{-}\kern-0.4em D}
%\usepackage[T1]{tipa}
%\usepackage[T1]{fontenc}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Credits}

\section*{Mercenarium Playtesters}

\Dr achen Koester
\end{document}
```

Comment: Do you mean `Đ`?

Comment: `\setmainfont{Futura}` means that you are using the `fontspec` package, which runs under XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX. These two formats are Unicode-aware, so you don't need `inputenc`, neither do you need `fontenc`

Comment: do not use inputenc or fontenc packages with xetex

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not sure Futura is good for extensive text. Anyway, if you use `fontspec` you can directly input the character or use `\DJ`.

```
\documentclass[twoside, openany]{book}
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Futura}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Credits}

\section*{Mercenarium Playtesters}

Đachen Koester or \DJ achen Koester

\end{document}
```

Beware that this could also be U+00D0 LATIN CAPITAL LETTER ETH (used in Icelandic and other Nordic languages). The two characters are similar in uppercase form, but differ in lowercase.

U+00F0 LATIN SMALL LETTER ETH ð (lowercase version of U+00D0 Ð)

U+0111 LATIN SMALL LETTER D WITH STROKE đ (lowercase version of U+0110 Đ)

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. When I build your MWE on my end, I get a box instead of the character. Am I missing something about having this character downloaded on my end?

Comment: @Pyro1368 It probably depends on what kind of Futura font you have. I have the one coming with the OS.

Comment: After playing round a bit, I found out that I was supposed to use the command \DH instead of \DJ.